# What is the BNF (or BNF-like) syntax for a specific number of repetitions?

Tags: language-agnostic, language-design, syntax, specifications, definition

I would like to write something like

```
<byte> ::= <bit>*8
```

to mean that a `<byte>` is a sequence of exactly 8 `<bit>`'s.

Is there a way to do this in BNF[[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus-Naur_form)][[2](https://sci-hub.tw/https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1064049)] or a widely used extension of BNF? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In BNF, you would just define that by repeating the symbol:

```
<byte> ::= <bit> <bit> <bit> <bit> <bit> <bit> <bit> <bit>
```

---

On the other hand, [Augmented Backus–Naur form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) defines repetition:

```
<example> ::= *<bit>
```

The above means:

```
<example> ::= "" | <bit> <example>
```

So, none or more `bit`.

For one or more you can say:

```
<example> ::= 1*<bit>
```

For a range (for example one to four), inclusive:

```
<example> ::= 1*4<bit>
```

Or a fixed number:

```
<example> ::= 8*8<bit>
```

Which you can also write like this:

```
<example> ::= 8<bit>
```

Note: In ABNF, `<` and `>` are optional.

Comment: Thanks. Based on the [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form), it looks like this is called "specific repetition."